# Watson Iot, some Rules aren't triggered even when condition are met

Tags: json, eclipse, triggers, watson-iot

I have a Device (a virtual one) on Watson IoT, which i connect using Eclipse Jee ( I'm using the Oxygen version) on this side everything is regular and code do what it is supposed to do, connect the device, which receives the Json i want to send.

Now, the problem is, this device has a schema with two events that needs to be triggered:

- The first, which works, triggers when the temperature is above 30 C°
- The second, triggers when the disk space used is above 20%

this two parameters are sent in the same Json, in a structure like

```
cpu{Temperature: 'something' },
diskSpace{... : ... , percentage: 'something' }
```

both events are activated, both refers to the same schema and both should sent an e-mail when triggered, but i receive only the temperature alert. I tried to de-activate the temperature rule, since I thought that maybe, there was some kinda conflict triggering simultaneaously two sending on the same email address, but still the space rule don't send the e-mail.

Why?

(I'm using only java code and Eclipse, no Phyton, no nodeJs, no redNode)

Comment: Please provide more details about how the schema is configured - a screenshot to show the parameters you defined and if they are string, etc. would be helpful.  Also check your device properties in the sensor information of the dashboard to be sure they match what you are monitoring in schema - https://console.ng.bluemix.net/docs/services/IoT/im_schemas.html#iotrtinsights_task

Comment: Thanks, i've checked the properties, they are set the right way.

Anyway, I somehow resolved the problem. Now I get both alerts.
I think it was some kinda network problem.